# One div inside second div with scrollbar

Tags: css, sass

I have a table which is placed inside some `div`. I want the table to be always inside this div. If its height is `25%` and table's height is `50%`, the scroll bar should appear.

Here's the plunker: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/fmFJ0vEreiX6OkvxVGjr?p=preview)

Comment: As I checked your plunker. You already put ``overflow-y: scroll`` so I'm not sure I understand your question right! Btw, the rule that you've put in body, should be ``box-sizing`` instead of ``boxing-size``.

Comment: @Ardian, He changed his Plunker after I posted my answer to see if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to scroll within the container div? Have you tried "overflow:scroll"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your `.container` class

```
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The `overflow-y` will only place a scrollbar on the right side, while `overflow` will place a scrollbar on the right and bottom (which I'm assuming you don't want xD).

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6gLgp4hw/1/)